# Why cant I get a real IDFA,after use a new certificate in my app?

Tags: xcode

In my early app version,the user IDFA I get is always match to the idfa in my test phone(I use a APP caller The identifiers to look up).

But after a new version with a new certificate, the IDFA I get is always different from my local,but in a right format

---

For example,I open my app with IDFA:D82A892B-969D-4F27-A363-BE72357D9460
but the idfa I get from my serveris:385680FF-A55E-4765-BB35-AB8D92894E24

I don't understand why and how it works exactly.

Someone has an idea ? Thank you. Regards,